# In Python I am trying to call a function but it is not working for variable

Tags: python-2.7, paramiko

Below is the function

def lldp(client1):

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = client1.exec_command('show lldp neighbor interface' + " " + q[0] + " " + '| match add')
z = stdout.read()
A = z.split()
A = A[9]
print A
if A == ':':
    sys.exit()
```

return

Variable A will be assigned with some value and when i call this function into another script like below

lldp(client1)

I am getting below error.

NameError: name ‘A’ is not defined.

Tried defining as global A inside function still on luck 
Tried return A still no luck.

Comment: Please fix your indenting.

Comment: indenting for return ?

Comment: Take a look at the question.  Does it look right?  If not, fix it.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 1):

I am able to figure out.

return A missing in function and in script A = lldp() is missing.

working now.